# Sending a GET HTTPS request with basic auth to an API

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, https, get

I'm trying to send a GET request to a user/pass protected API. I'm using Javascript and adding in an "auth" option.

```
const https = require('https');

const headers= {
    'Accepts' : 'application/json',
}

const options = {
  hostname: 'api.com/more/info',
  port: 443,
  path: '/',
  auth: 'username:password',
  method: 'GET'
};

const req = https.request(options, (res) => {
  console.log('statusCode:', res.statusCode);
  console.log('headers:', res.headers);

  res.on('data', (d) => {
    process.stdout.write(d);
  });
});

req.on('error', (e) => {
  console.error(e);
});
req.end();
```

The error I receive when this code is run is:

```
Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND api/com/more/info
    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:66:26) {
  errno: -3008,
  code: 'ENOTFOUND',
  syscall: 'getaddrinfo',
  hostname: 'api.com/more/info'
}
```

The hostname has been changed for anonymity.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance for any advice.

Comment: Have you tried with Postman to send the request? Just to make sure that the DNS server which your computer pointing to can resolve `api.com/more/info`.

Answer (score 2):

`'api.com/more/info'` is probably not your hostname.

Try with these options instead:

```js
const options = {
  hostname: 'api.com',
  port: 443,
  path: '/more/info',
  auth: 'username:password',
  method: 'GET'
};
```